# Copy activity met storage operation failure at 'Sink' side. Error message from storage execution

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy Azure tables between 2 storage accounts using `Azure Data Factory`. Able to copy most of the tables except one. Getting below error message after copying over a million records from that table. I assume, one or more records are large.

Source and Sink both are `Azure Table Storage`.

> Copy activity met storage operation failure at 'Sink' side. Error
>   message from storage execution : The remote server returned an error:
>   (413) The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum
>   permissible limit.. The request body is too large and exceeds the
>   maximum permissible limit.

My question Is there any maximum permissible limit for request body for copying ? If yes, can we configure it in the data factory pipeline activity or dataset configuration ?

Comment: Do you set vaule for the `writeBatchSize` ? If it is that case, as far as  I know that write batch operation is limited to a 4MB. And please have a try again while set `writeBatchSize =1`

Comment: I had set writeBatchSize = 0.

Comment: Is there anyway we can configure `Maximum Permissible Limit `in the activity ?

Comment: I can't find a way to configure the `Maximum Permissible Limit` in the activity. From the exception, it seems that records are large as you mentioned. Do you set `azureTableInsertType = merged` (default)? If it is that case, please have a try to set `azureTableInsertType = replaced`